# MAC App rejected for using entitlement com.apple.developer.maps

Tags: macos, cocoa, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I have submitted updated version(3.10) of my mac app.

They are saying that **my app uses the entitlement com.apple.developer.maps, but does not have "matching functionality within the app."**

I have tried several builds, so its not just a fluke.

I have checked the Capabilities tab of the target for my app and my helper app, and both are correct. I have checked the entitlements file for both the main app and the helper app and both are correct.

Previous versions of this app have been approved successfully by apple, but updated version gets rejected.

What can be the issue?

How can I solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue at last years WWDC. Maps entitlement in the helper app but nowhere used and not activated in the Capabilities tab. It took over one hour for the evangelist and me to find & fix the issue.

My problem was that I had a wildcard Provisioning Profile that included Maps. It somehow got into the project. 
Unfortunately I am not sure anymore how we fixed the problem.
Try checking your other profiles for the entitlement. Check them in Xcode & the Developer Portal.